# How to convert JS object to JSON encoded string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, string

I have tried this but it is not working properly. It is just giving regular JS string and not in the JSON format

```
function convert(obj) {
  let ret = "{";

  for (let k in obj) {
    let v = obj[k];

    if (typeof v === "function") {
      v = v.toString();
    } else if (v instanceof Array) {
      v = JSON.stringify(v);
    } else if (typeof v === "object") {
      v = convert(v);
    } else {
      v = `"${v}"`;
    }

    ret += `\n  ${k}: ${v},`;
  }

  ret += "\n}";

  return ret;
}
```

Input:

```
const input = {
 rules3: {
    fn1: ()=> {
     setTimeout(function abc() {console.log("aaaaaaaa")}, 3000);
    }
  }
}
```

Expected output:

I need to JSON.parse the converted String back. So below is an example of expected output

```
'const input = {
 "rules3": {
    "fn1": ()=> {
     "setTimeout(function abc() {console.log("aaaaaaaa")}, 3000)"
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Can you please add input and expected output as well?

Comment: This is example object:   const input = {
 rules3: {
    fn1: ()=> {
     setTimeout(function abc() {console.log("aaaaaaaa")}, 3000);
    }
  }
}

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use `JSON.stringify()` on your object. You don't typically need to stringify functions, just the object data is enough

Answer (score 1):

As you know, JSON does not support functions and regex. It looks like you want to stringify the function, and store as JSON. Instead of handcrafting a stringify function you can use the `JSON.stringify()` function with a replacer helper function:

```js
const input = {
  text: 'hi',
  numbner: 123,
  array: [1, 2, 3],
  regex: /^-?\d+(:?\.\d+)?$/,
  rules3: {
    fn1: () => {
      setTimeout(function abc() {
        console.log("aaaaaaaa")
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
}

function replacer(key, val) {
  if (typeof val === 'function' || val && val.constructor === RegExp) {
    return val.toString();
  }
  return val;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(input, replacer, 2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "text": "hi",
  "numbner": 123,
  "array": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "regex": "/^-?\\d+(:?\\.\\d+)?$/",
  "rules3": {
    "fn1": "() => {\n      setTimeout(function abc() {\n        console.log(\"aaaaaaaa\")\n      }, 3000);\n    }"
  }
}
```

In the same way you can use a replacer function to restore the object using `JSON.parse()`.

Note that because the function and regex are turned into a string it is not deterministic what is a string, what is a function, and what is a regex. Hence you might want to annotate the stringified function and regex to make it deterministic.

Docs:

- `JSON.stringify()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify
- `JSON.parse()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: @PeterTheony I am having issues with writing replacer function on parse. Could you please post the code?

Comment: @AdityaBVijay: Can you show in your question what you have tried? SO is not a free service to produce code